# How to jump back and forth between previous/next cursor positions, limited to current buffer only?

Tags: vim

I like the functionality of `<C-O>` and `<C-I>` to go back and forth to different positions. But many times I would prefer to stay within the current buffer, and always get taken by surprise when a new buffer opens up replacing the one I was looking at.

(1) Is there a way to achieve this? i.e., limit `<C-O>` and `<C-I>` to the same buffer?

(2) Is there a way to visit all cursor moves, even those that are not normally considered jumps, e.g. `10k`?

Comment: I found a solution in another question, check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066456/vim-how-to-prevent-jumps-out-of-current-buffer

Answer (score 5):

As for moving in the same file, check out the `''` command.  It will jump back and forth between the current location and the last jump.

Comment: Thanks. But I was hoping for a much longer stack of jumps tracked, not just the the last one.