# How to prevent leaving the current buffer when traversing the jump list in Vim?

Tags: vim, buffer, jump-list

I frequently have several buffers open in my Vim session. This means that my jump list stores locations from several buffers. However, frequently when I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> keyboard shortcut to jump to a previous location, I do not want to leave the buffer and want to jump to previous locations “local” to the current buffer. How do I do this?

For example, assume my jump list looks as follows:

```
4   10   1 ~/aaa.m
3   20   1 ~/aaa.m
2   12   2 ~/xxx.m
1   15   1 ~/aaa.m
```

I want to jump to line 15 of file `aaa.m` the first time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. Importantly, the next time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, I do not want to jump to file `xxx.m`. Rather, I want to jump to line 20 of file `aaa.m`, that is, my previous location within the “current” buffer. The default Vim behaviour, though, is to take me to to line 12 of file `xxx.m`.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: This might be a better question for superuser, stackoverflow questions(and answers) tend relate directly to coding. superuser.com is run by the same people but focuses on using software.

Comment: @David Waters, no. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925/160504

Comment: Would using the `changelist` fit your needs? You can use `g;` and `g,` to move back and forth though the change list.

Comment: @Peter Rincker, thanks for your response. However, this does not solve the problem as I need to jump to previous cursor positions and **not** just the change positions. This frequently happens when I am searching strings in a code and jump from one function to another, without editing the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following jump-list traversing function. It steps successively
from one jump-list location to another (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> depending on the values that are
supplied to its `back` and `forw` arguments), and stops if the current
location is in the same buffer as that buffer it has started from.
If it is not possible to find a jump-list location that belongs to the
current buffer, the function returns to the position in the jump list
that was the current one before the function was called.

```
function! JumpWithinFile(back, forw)
    let [n, i] = [bufnr('%'), 1]
    let p = [n] + getpos('.')[1:]
    sil! exe 'norm!1' . a:forw
    while 1
        let p1 = [bufnr('%')] + getpos('.')[1:]
        if n == p1[0] | break | endif
        if p == p1
            sil! exe 'norm!' . (i-1) . a:back
            break
        endif
        let [p, i] = [p1, i+1]
        sil! exe 'norm!1' . a:forw
    endwhile
endfunction
```

To use this function as a
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>-replacement
locked to the current buffer, create mappings as it is shown below.

```
nnoremap <silent> <c-k> :call JumpWithinFile("\<c-i>", "\<c-o>")<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-j> :call JumpWithinFile("\<c-o>", "\<c-i>")<cr>
```

Comment: eeck. that is sick. and crafty. Giving you points for swimming against the stream

Comment: Thanks for writing that code, really interesting solution. It _almost_ works, with a couple of niggles. Firstly, if a directory is in my jump-list (this could be the case because I browsed a directory to open a file), it opens the netrw browser in the current buffer and then gets stuck there. Secondly, when the function reaches the end of the jump-list, it keeps jumping between the last two locations (when `Ctrl+k` is pressed). Is it possible that it either loops through the jump-list, or just stays at the last location?

Comment: @sehe:  This feels against the grain for me, too.  (And personally I would not try to cut corners of default jump-list behavior.)  But it's interesting (and a bit hackish) to try to find out a way solving this problem.

Comment: @vimgm:  Could you please minimize an example of incorrect behavior and describe it a little more detail.  At the moment I can't reproduce neither problems.

Comment: @ib: Sure. If jump-list looks like following:
 [3   15   2 ~/xxx.m]
 [2   10   2 ~]
 [1   15   1 ~/aaa.m]
(This could happen if you opened `aaa.m` using the command `:e .` from command line) then pressing `Ctrl-k` twice opens the Netrw directory listing for directory `~`. This is undesirable as I want the buffer to keep displaying file aaa.m. Secondly, if the jump-list is as in my original example above, when cursor gets to line 10, `Ctrl-k` makes it jump to line 20. Pressing `Ctrl-k` again makes it jump to line 10 and so on. I would like it to either remain at line 10 or loop back to line 15.

Comment: @vimgm:  The problem with seemingly infinite jump loop between two location was caused by a mistake: the line `sil! exe 'norm!' . i . a:back` should be `sil! exe 'norm!' . (i-1) . a:back`.  The answer is updated.

Comment: @vimgm:  Trying to reproduce your issue with Netrw I did the following.  In shell: `$cd /tmp`, `$rm ~/.viminfo` (to clear jump-list), `$echo -e "test\ntest" >t`; then in Vim: `:e.`, `/^t` `Enter`, `Enter`, `2G`.  (The script from the answer was appended to `~/.vimrc`.)  Then, `Ctrl`-`K` moves the cursor to the first line and keeps it there while pressing `Ctrl`-`K` again and again.  Netrw buffer does not appear.

Comment: @ib: OK, this works perfectly now. The infinite loop has stopped. I think the Netrw problem was due to the fact that I use the Tabbar plugin (which helps manage switching between buffers) along with Netrw. I have now disabled Netrw and am using NERDTree instead. Everything works like a charm. (Oh, you probably want to remove the `echo`s from the code above). Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @vimgm:  It works for me with both Netrw and NERDTree (I prefer the former, by the way).  Oh, of course, I should clear the debug output out of the code.  Don't mention it, I'm glad that my code helped!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [EnhancedJumps plugin](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-EnhancedJumps) will help.

With this plugin installed, the jump to another buffer is only done if the same jump command is repeated once more immediately afterwards.